# insert of multiple arrays fails on empty values

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I'm inserting several arrays to my mysql table from a dynamic form. The only problem I have is when I leave one comment input blank it won't insert any more comments from the comments array but it does continue to insert the rest of the other arrays. I'm not so sure how to handle it. Was thinking an if statement..

Edit:
I've adjusted the code to reflect my actual situation. I now know it's because all of my arrays are the same number of values except the comment array. How do I insert the comment where it's index matches the cardid?

$cardid array

```
Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 1 [2] => 1 [3] => 1 [4] => 1 [5] => 2 [6] => 2 [7] => 2 [8] => 2 [9] => 2 [10] => 3 [11] => 3 [12] => 3 [13] => 3 [14] => 3 [15] => 4 [16] => 4 [17] => 4 [18] => 4 [19] => 4 [20] => 5 [21] => 5 [22] => 5 [23] => 5 [24] => 5 [25] => 6 [26] => 6 [27] => 6 [28] => 6 [29] => 6 [30] => 7 [31] => 7 [32] => 7 [33] => 7 [34] => 7 [35] => 8 [36] => 8 [37] => 8 [38] => 8 [39] => 8 [40] => 9 [41] => 9 [42] => 9 [43] => 9 [44] => 9 [45] => 10 [46] => 10 [47] => 10 [48] => 10 [49] => 10 [50] => 11 [51] => 11 [52] => 11 [53] => 11 [54] => 11 [55] => 12 [56] => 12 [57] => 12 [58] => 12 [59] => 12 )
```

$comment array

```
Array ( [0] => test1 [1] => [2] => test3 [3] => [4] => [5] => [6] => [7] => [8] => [9] => [10] => [11] => )
```

Here's my loop.

```
    $comment =  $_POST['comment'];

    for ($i=0; $i < count($_POST['cardid']); $i++ ) {

    $card_id = $_POST['cardid'][$i];
    $card_type = $_POST['cardtype'][$i];
    $top_y = $_POST['top_y'][$i];
    $left_x = $_POST['left_x'][$i];
    $pest_count = $_POST['pestcount'][$i];
    $pest_name = $_POST['pestname'][$i];

  // I tried grabing it like this

    foreach($card_id as $key=>$value){
if(in_array($key, $_POST['comment'])) {
    $comment = $value ;
}
}

     if($pest_count <> ''){

        $sql ="INSERT INTO pest_table (pest_name,pest_count,card_id,card_type,top_y,left_x,comments)
        VALUES (:pest_name,:pest_count,:card_id,:card_type,:top_y,:left_x,:comments)"; 
        $q = $pdo->prepare($sql);     
$q->execute(array(':pest_name'=>$pest_name,':pest_count'=>$pest_count,':card_id'=>$card_id,':card_type'=>$card_type,':top_y'=>$top_y,':left_x'=>$left_x,':comments'=>$comment)); 

         }

      }
```

Comment: use if($pest_count != '') not <>

Comment: if($pest_count != '') returns the same result. That part of the code works as needed not allowing an insert if any of the number inputs are empty. It's just that comment array that won't insert anything past the first blank value.

Comment: I tried adding an if statement to check for the NULL value but it still stops inserting any comments after the first blank one.  foreach ($comment as $key => $value) {
    if (is_null($value)) {
         $comment[$key] = "";
    }
}

Comment: I think I now know what this issue is. I'm checking for blank pest_count and not inserting any data but that array can have multiple inputs where the comment input will be one per group of pest_count inputs. How can I pass the comment to each pest_count that's not blank?

Comment: I've done some checking around and understand the issue but can't find how grab the comment that goes with each card id. I edited the code above to show the array structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($_POST['cardid']); $i++) {
    $card_id = $_POST['cardid'][$i];
    $card_type = $_POST['cardtype'][$i];
    $top_y = $_POST['top_y'][$i];
    $left_x = $_POST['left_x'][$i];
    $pest_count = $_POST['pestcount'][$i];
    $pest_name = $_POST['pestname'][$i];

    $commentKey = $card_id-1;
    $comment = $_POST['comment'][$commentKey];

    if (!empty($pest_count)) {
        $sql ="INSERT INTO `pest_table` (`pest_name`, `pest_count`, `card_id`, `card_type`, `top_y`, `left_x`, `comments`) VALUES (:pest_name, :pest_count, :card_id, :card_type, :top_y, :left_x, :comments)";
        $q = $pdo->prepare($sql);

        // All data passed into execute() function are treated as PDO::PARAM_STR! It's better to use PDO's bindParam() or bindValue().
        $q->execute(array(
            ':pest_name' => $pest_name,
            ':pest_count' => $pest_count,
            ':card_id' => $card_id,
            ':card_type' => $card_type,
            ':top_y' => $top_y,
            ':left_x' => $left_x,
            ':comments' => $comment
        ));
    }
}
```

Your card_id's are indexed from 1 to N. But comments are indexed from 0.
To get comment by card_id you need to use `$comment = $_POST['comment'][$commentKey];` where `$commentKey = $card_id-1;`

Comment: Thank you bossqone. I have searched off and on since I last posted this and never found anything that worked. Nor did I find anything that simple. I understand what it's doing now. Thanks again. I clicked on the bounty for your answer but it says I have to wait 7 hours.